# Malloc fails and the logging, isn't this foolish?

Tags: malloc

Here's the code, isn't this pointless?

```
  unsigned char * rngBuf = malloc(nBytes);
    if(!rngBuf) {
        DDLogError(@"Unable to allocate buffer for random bytes.");
        [self displayHUDMessage:@"Memory Error."];
        return;
    }
```

If the malloc fails, why would logging or displaying a hud succeed?

What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: The `malloc` may fail because there aren't `nBytes` of contiguous memory available to fill that allocation. It doesn't necessarily mean there is **no** memory available. Logging or the display can also have a buffer already allocated before the call to `malloc` fails.

Comment: DD might, but displayHUDMessage won't.  It's not meant for that.

Comment: OK, but you asked about logging as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It would be foolish only if displaying the error required nbytes or more memory from the heap (vs from the stack, static or quoted strings, or compile-time resolved string macros like **FILE** and **FUNCTION**).

I'm not familiar with your API, but I make sure to use statically allocated print buffers in my code. Here's an example.

```
//  ... file management data structures...
typedef struct {
    FILE     *fp;
    size_t   knt;           //  record counter for use when needed
    ULLNG    bytes;         //  total number of bytes written to .fp file handle
    char     name[128];
    char     mode_str[8];   
} FILE_DESC, *pFILE_DESC;

typedef struct {
    FILE_DESC   *fargs; // for the price of a FILE pointer we get all the details :)
    size_t      bytes;
    char        buff[1<<20];
} SMART_PRN_BUFF, pSMART_PRN_BUFF;
// ---- allocate 4 static/global smart write-buffers here
static  SMART_PRN_BUFF  FiPrn[4];
```

Paired with an initializer near the top of main() like...

```
FILE_DESC   File[4] = {{NULL,0,0,"","w+t"},{NULL,0,0,"","w+t"},{NULL,0,0,"","r+b"}, {NULL,0,0,"","w"}};


printf("\nProcessing %i file names in \n%s", argc -1, argv[0]);
for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    if(NULL != argv[i+1])   {
        strcpy(File[i].name, argv[i+1]);
        File[i].fp = fopen(File[i].name, File[i].mode_str);
        if(NULL==File[i].fp) {
            printf("\nFile %s could not be opened in %s mode at line %i in %s\n--- ABORTING PROGRAM ---\n\n",
                    File[i].name, File[i].mode_str, __LINE__, __FILE__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            printf("\nFile %s opened in %s mode", File[i].name, File[i].mode_str);
        }
    }
    FiPrn[i].fargs = &File[i];
}
```

Usage is like ...

```
FiPrn[ERR].bytes += sprintf(FiPrn[ERR].buff, 
        "\nSize of FiPrn structure is %llu", (ULLNG)sizeof(FiPrn));
WriteToFile(&FiPrn[ERR]);
```

As you might have noticed, I have to use printf() vs sprintf() until I get the files opened and can write to them, but the static memory is allocated as SMART_PRN_BUFF.buff[1<<20], which gives me 1 megabyte for each of the 4 files I've provisioned here before I even attempt to open the files they will write to.

So I am completely confident I can print returns from malloc() and calloc() a few lines later, like this...

```
if(NULL == Sequencer)
    FiPrn[ERR].bytes += sprintf(FiPrn[ERR].buff + FiPrn[ERR].bytes,
    "\nCalloc() for Sequencer returned %p at line %i in file %s in function %s()\n",STD_ERR(Sequencer));
```

Where STD_ERR() is a macro that helps insure the code emits uniform error messages, like this...

```
#define STD_ERR(rtn) rtn,__LINE__,__FILE__,__FUNCTION__ // uniform error handling
```